# Sort Spark Dataframe with two columns in different order

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let's say, I have a table like this:

```
A,B
2,6
1,2
1,3
1,5
2,3
```

I want to sort it with ascending order for column `A` but within that I want to sort it in descending order of column `B`, like this:

```
A,B
1,5
1,3
1,2
2,6
2,3
```

I have tried to use `orderBy("A", desc("B"))` but it gives an error.

How should I write the query using dataframe in Spark 2.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Column method [desc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@desc:org.apache.spark.sql.Column), as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (2,6), (1,2), (1,3), (1,5), (2,3)
).toDF("A", "B")

df.orderBy($"A", $"B".desc).show
// +---+---+
// |  A|  B|
// +---+---+
// |  1|  5|
// |  1|  3|
// |  1|  2|
// |  2|  6|
// |  2|  3|
// +---+---+
```

Comment: I like to be as explicit as possible, so I would use the [asc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@asc:org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on the first column _(`$"A".asc`)_, even if the default behavior is to sort ascending.

Answer (score 5):

[`desc`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#desc()) is the correct method to use, however, not that it is a method in the `Columnn` class. It should therefore be applied as follows:

```
df.orderBy($"A", $"B".desc)
```

`$"B".desc` returns a column so `"A"` must also be changed to `$"A"` (or `col("A")` if spark implicits isn't imported).

Comment: df.orderBy($"A"desc, $"B".asc) solved my problem. Great.